# Как подключить Gii в Yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2, gii

Я установить его через Composer, прописал настройки в ***frontend/config/main.php***, но по адресу /index.php?r=gii ничего не показывается, то есть показывается стандартная страница. Что я сделал не так?

frontend/config/main.php

```
'bootstrap' => ['gii'],
'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    // ...
],
```

Comment: `прописал настройки в frontend/config/main.php` ......какие? добавьте конфиг в вопрос ....... и есть ли с `common` конфиг `main-local`?

Comment: Добавил конфиг в вопрос. в папке `common` есть конфиг `main-local`

Comment: Это какой-то маааааленький конфиг. вы его весь выложите. А в `common/main-local` есть строки `'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,

        ],` ? .....а во `frontend` и `backend` есть main-local? там же уже gii должен быть прописан

Comment: в `common/main-local` такого нету, такое есть в `frontend/config/main`. и да, в `frontend/config/main-local` gii уже прописан

Comment: В этом наверное и проблема. это позволяет писать красивые урлы. Т.е. можно писать http://mysite.ru/gii  ....правда при наличии опции `'request'=>[
            'baseUrl'=>'',
        ],` ...... А если поставить `'enablePrettyUrl' => false,` то можно писать `index.php?r=gii`  и раз в main-local подключен gii, то в main писать `'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    // ...
],` вроде и не обязательно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. frontend/config/main.php

   'urlManager' => [
               'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
               'showScriptName' => false,
   ],

2 . frontend/config/main-local.php

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];
}
```

теперь  можете зайти site.com/gii
(если у вас baseUrl=> '' для фронта)